# Is there an elegant solution to concatenating Dataframes as fixed element in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Arguably I can improve on function design choices in the first place, but currently I am in a situation where a function returns a tuple, or list, of dataframes pertaining to different data streams.
The idea is that each data stream separately needs to be concatenated at the end. For now limited to three, but scalable.

```
import pandas as pd

def spit_out_three_dfs():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp": ["x", "y"], "Data": [1,1]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp": ["x", "y"], "Data": [2,2]})
    df3 = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp": ["x", "y"], "Data": [3,3]})
    return df1, df2, df3

df1_concat, df2_concat, df3_concat = map(lambda x: pd.concat(x), [spit_out_three_dfs() for i in range(3)])
```

will yield all 3 dataframes to return as

```
df1_concat
Out[14]: 
  Timestamp  Data
0         x     1
1         y     1
0         x     2
1         y     2
0         x     3
1         y     3
```

instead of the wished for:

```
df1_concat
Out[14]: 
  Timestamp  Data
0         x     1
1         y     1
0         x     1
1         y     1
0         x     1
1         y     1
```

and similarly data stream 2 in df2_concat, etc.
What I am explicitly looking for is a way to concatenate the three streams in one go.

What I can do, is to merge the streams and later filter/query: this runs into memory problems.

Another effort I can make, is to run a nested list comprehension to pick the xth element every time, which will exhaust the generator, requiring me to run the entire operation again for the next element.
For 3 data streams this is manageable, but horribly inefficient still.

Is there a pandas wizard out there who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: I am not sure I understand fully what you are looking for but does this help? `df1_concat, df2_concat, df3_concat = map(lambda x: pd.concat([x]*3), spit_out_three_dfs())`

Comment: Works for the example problem, checking on the larger set.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem, but what if you just did: `1) dfs = [df1, df2, df3]`, 2) `df = pd.concat(dfs)` 3) `df['Data'] = df1['Data']` or `df['Data'] = df1['Data'].min()` ?

Comment: @It_is_Chris: they are not repetitive data, so I cannot just duplicate 1 data file and get away with it.

Comment: @DavidErickson: For 2 files, there are thousands in practice, it'll end up with a list of length 2, each entry being a tuple or list of 3 dataframes of varying length. `df1 = pd.concat([dfs[0][0], dfs[1][0]]) ; df2 = pd.concat([dfs[0][1], dfs[1][1]])`etc.

Comment: @Uvar can you explain your expected output further for `df1_concat` Why are the indices repeated? Why is the data repeated? Can you provided sample data that better illustrates the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had understood it well, you want to concatenate data coming from different streams, that are initially stored in a structure such as:

```py
[ (df_stm0_0, df_stm1_0, ...), (df_stm0_1, df_stm1_1, ...), ...]
```

If that's the case. I believe you're applying the concatenation function at the wrong level and you should use a the zip iterator to make lists like:

```py
[[df_stm0_0, df_stm0_1, ...], [df_stm1_0, df_stm1_1, ...], ... ]
```

Your return line should look like this:

```py
df1_concat, df2_concat, df3_concat = map(lambda x: pd.concat, zip(*[spit_out_three_dfs() for i in range(3)]))
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'll go hang my head in shame and thanks!  Actually did try a similar solution, but ended up zipping on the wrong level. >_>